# Custom build key binding sublime text

Tags: build, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, key-bindings

I've made a custom build in sublime which runs my program and it works fine. But I have the Makefile build as default. Is there a way, to let <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> use the default build (in my case Makefile) and have another shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) use another build. If yes, how?

I tried using this :

```
[
   { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+b"], "command": "build buildName" }
]
```

but it isn't working and watching at the sublime documentation this command is only for the default build selected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

The actual syntax of the keybinding should be like so:

```js
{ "keys": ["f1"], "command": "build", "args": {"build_system": "Packages/Python/Python3.sublime-build"} },
```

I would actually recommend against using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> as your custom keybinding, as it is already applied to the "Build With" command.